# which version of MAMP is compatbile with mac 10.5.8

Tags: macos, mamp

Which version of MAMP should I download for MAC 10.5.8?

The latest version isn't compatible and I found nowhere the information.

Please help me.

Comment: version 1.9.6 is working fine here